# Save outlook excel attachments and concatenate the data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement that I am doing everyday and spending around 3 hours to do that. I would like it to be automated so that I can save time.

1. Every day I will get an email which contains around 100 attachments in *.msg format (Attachments are actually mails from different vendors).
2. In the *.msg files there will be one Excel file and this Excel file contains one line of data.
3. What I would like to do is Extract the first email attachments (which is in .Msg format) and extract the Excel file in each .Msg attachment and then copy the data from the XLS files into a new Excel file (Consolidating the data from each Excel attachment for calculations)!!

Can some one please provide a way to automate this process in vba macro and I would require detailed step as I am a newbie into the coding area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as I can get to automating this using VBA. It's a semi-automatic solution that will require you to save the .msg attachments in a folder first and then open them all *manually* (i.e. select all, right-click one and chose Open). I tested this on 98 emails being opened at once, my Outlook slowed down a bit towards the end but it did not crash. The code itself takes under 3 minutes to complete the task.
But first, some assumptions were made based on the info provided:

- All the .msg attachments are in one email message - if they are not, you may need to repeat step 1 as many times as necessary.
- The Excel files inside the .msg files are in ".xls" format. If they are in ".xls**x**" or other Excel format simply modify the relevant lines of code under Step 3.
- You stated that the Excel files contain just 1 row of data - the below assumes it's row 1 in sheet 1. If not, the code will need to be adjusted slightly before it works.
- Also, the solution ignores cell formatting in the Excel files - only the values from cells will be copied - this can be modified if needed.
- You have some understanding of VBA, know how to insert module, compile, run and edit code in VB Editor - if not, just post your questions in a comment below, I'll be happy to help further.

**The solution:**

Step 1 - Save all the ".msg" attachments to a folder.

Step 2 - Select all emails in the folder and open them - this should open multiple Outlook inspector windows.

Step 3 - In Excel, activate VB Editor and paste the below code in a module:

```
Sub GetAttachments()
'loops through Outlook inspector windows extracting .xls attachments into a folder

    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Insp As Object
    Dim Att As Object
    Dim FldPth As String
    Dim myFname As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder with attachments", 0)
    If oShell Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Folder was not selected", vbCritical: Exit Sub

    FldPth = oShell.self.Path

    'loop through open outlook windows (inspectors)
    'use reversed loop, otherwise every second iteration will be skipped
    For i = olApp.Inspectors.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Insp = olApp.Inspectors.Item(i)
        'loop through attachments in the email message
        For Each Att In Insp.CurrentItem.Attachments
            myFname = Att.Filename

            'if the attached file is an xls type, save it in a folder
            If LCase(Right(myFname, 4)) = ".xls" Then
                Att.SaveAsFile FldPth & "\" & myFname
            End If
        Next Att
        'close the inspector window
        Insp.Close olDiscard
    Next i
    Set oShell = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
Sub GetDataFromWbks()
'loops through Excel files in selected folder extracting data from first row in sheet 1 into active worksheet

    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Dim srcWbk As Workbook
    Dim dstWs As Worksheet
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim dstRng As Range
    Dim FldPth As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder with attachments", 0)
    If oShell Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Folder was not selected", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    FldPth = oShell.self.Path

    Set dstWs = ActiveSheet
    Set dstRng = dstWs.Rows(1)
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'loop through all files in folder
    For Each f In FSO.GetFolder(FldPth).Files
        If LCase(Right(f.Name, 4)) = ".xls" Then
            'show progress in Excel's status bar
            Application.StatusBar = i
            'open xls file
            Set srcWbk = Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
            'set source range
            Set srcRng = srcWbk.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows(1)
            'copy source range to destination range
            dstWs.Range(srcRng.Address).Offset(i).Value = srcRng.Value
            i = i + 1
            'close workbook
            srcWbk.Close
        End If
    Next f
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set oShell = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Step 4 - Run the "GetAttachments" procedure. When prompted, select the folder you saved your attachments in. The procedure should extract all the Excel attachments from .msg files into the same folder.

Step 5 - Once done (PopUp box showed up), activate the Excel worksheet you want your data to be copied into (I suggest you use a new empty worksheet here) and run the "GetDataFromWbks" procedure -  again, select your folder when prompted. You can watch the progress in Excel's status bar.

Step 6 - That's it, enjoy the saved time!

Comment: Terrific!! I tried initial round of testing and its works like a charm...Thanks a lot @JK2017 i will do some more testing and I will let you know incase if any issues. Once again Thanks a hell lot :) :)

Comment: May I ask if there is any way to hard code the Headings in the Row 1 before printing the data via "GetDataFromWbks" procedure.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly add any headings you need. Try the following: turn on Excel's macro recorder and add the headings you require, apply formatting, etc. Then stop the recorder, go to VB Editor, examine the code that the recorder produced. At this point I'd suggest putting Excel worksheet and VBE side by side on your screen, removing the headings and stepping through the code with F8 again to see what each line of code does.

Comment: Code produced by macro recorder is usually somewhat excessive, i.e. for adding a value in a cell, the recorder uses at least two lines of code, i.e. `Range("A1").Select` and `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "example header"` you can change that to just `Range("A1").Value = "example header"` (there's no need to select a cell before changing it's value). Edit the recorded code as required and then you can call it in between the two procedures. To ensure the "GetDataFromWbks" procedure starts adding your data from row 2 instead of row 1 just move this line `i = i + 1` one row up.

Comment: Thank you. I have set the Header as `Range("A1").Value = "example header"` and that worked correctly.